# Spring JPA : Native SQL query across different custom repositories

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a criteria appender method, which I use to prepare where clause for a SQL native query in a custom repository. say, `com.abc.func1.repository.Pkg1RepositoryCustomImpl`

Now, a need is there to use the same query in a download functionality across different package. say, `com.abc.func1.repository.Pkg2RepositoryCustomImpl`

I don't want to autowire repository into repository and also want to avoid rewriting the same code. Hence, I am planning to place the SQL appender method inside `Entity/Model`, like a function
`public void appendCriteriaToNative(StringBuffer sqlQuery)`

Can anyone suggest if the approach is correct or is there some other better design for the same.

Comment: i dont't think idea of having sql appender in your entity is good way, it does not look clean. if you have same code in your custom repository, have you consider to your new repository extrends old one, or both of them extends one with shared functionality?

Comment: Yes, I did considered this option, but what I am appending to sqlQuery is the properies of entity. ex. if entity is **Profile** then I want to call `profile.appendCriteriaToNative(nativeQuery)` so that it appends like `"where PROFILE_NAME = " + profile.name` Now, If I make a base repository in new package then stuffing and outside entity to itself is not making absolute sense.

Comment: you could create class SqlAppender to be singleton, and inject it to your both repositories, SqlAppender could have method `appendCriteria(String nativeQuery, Entity entity);` you could create common interface for your entities. But this is not good solution because same as yours is vulnerable to sql inject

Comment: ok lemme check something around your suggestion ... Thanks for the help !!